# Convert a dictionary of nested lists to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a python dictionary as below:

```
dict1={808: [['a', 5.4, 'b'],
  ['c', 4.1 , 'b'],
  ['d', 3.7 , 'f']]}
```

I want to convert it into a data frame as below:

```
memberid  userid score related
808       a      5.4     b
808       c      4.1     b
808       d      3.7     f
```

I tried with code below:

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1,orient='index')
```

The results is not what I desired.

Could anybody know how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Will `dict1` always have a single key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's convert each nested list value to a DataFrame, and then call `pd.concat`.

```
columns = ['userid', 'score', 'related']

df_dict = {k : pd.DataFrame(v, columns=columns) for k, v in dict1.items()}

df = (pd.concat(df_dict)
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .rename_axis('memberid')
        .reset_index()
)
```

Or, in similar fashion—

```
df = pd.concat([
       pd.DataFrame(v, columns=columns, index=np.repeat(k, len(v))) 
       for k, v in dict1.items()
  ]
).rename_axis('memberid').reset_index()
```

```
df

   memberid userid  score related
0       808      a    5.4       b
1       808      c    4.1       b
2       808      d    3.7       f
```

Important note—this solution *also* works for multiple key-value pairs, where each key may not have the same number of lists. But because of this flexibility, it may become slow for large DataFrames. In that case, the modified solution below works if `dict1` contains *just one* entry—

```
k, v = list(dict1.items())[0]
pd.DataFrame(v, columns=columns, index=np.repeat(k, len(v))).reset_index()

   index userid  score related
0    808      a    5.4       b
1    808      c    4.1       b
2    808      d    3.7       f
```

Comment: I think I am so addicted to `pd.Series`, which is bad , sign

Comment: I know , it is inefficient for sure , trying my best :-)

Comment: Can't you just pass the list of lists directly to `pd.DataFrame` ?

Comment: @jpp If you have multiple key-value pairs, and if each key has varying number of lists, it becomes non-trivial to create `memberid` later. This is the most reliable approach imo.

Comment: Oh yes, I get the "if you have..."... but really depends on use case. If OP has a thousand of these dictionaries with one item each, then the simple method is better. If you have a variety of dictionary lengths, then yours is more flexible.

Comment: @jpp Fair point, you should mention this caveat in your solution :) Btw, your critique is very fair, I've tried to address it with an alternative solution quite like yours.

Comment: As my dictionary do have multiple keys and varies length so this solution works for me. Thank everybody!

Answer (score 5):

Using `pd.Series` couple of times

```
df=pd.Series(dict1).apply(pd.Series).stack().apply(pd.Series).reset_index().drop('level_1',1)
df.columns=['memberid','userid', 'score', 'related']
df
Out[626]: 
   memberid userid  score related
0       808      a    5.4       b
1       808      c    4.1       b
2       808      d    3.7       f
```

Answer (score 0):

Feeding your dictionary values into `pd.DataFrame` is one way.

Here we use `next(iter(some_view))` syntax to extract the only key and only value.

This is an efficient solution where you can guarantee your dictionary only has one key and the value is a list of lists.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(next(iter(dict1.values())), columns=['userid', 'score', 'related'])\
       .assign(memberid=next(iter(dict1.keys())))

print(df)

  userid  score related  memberid
0      a    5.4       b       808
1      c    4.1       b       808
2      d    3.7       f       808
```